# Is there a way to sort output data in SQL using custom groupings?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, case, presto

I am looking for a way to create a custom grouping of symbols in SQL in the output. For example, I have a table that looks something like this.

```
Symbol        Date        Value
AAPL       2020-06-05     1,000
JBLU       2020-06-20     1,000
JBLU       2020-06-24     1,000
AMZN       2020-06-08     1,000
AAPL       2020-06-11     1,000
MSFT       2020-06-27     1,000
RDSA       2020-06-11     1,000
AAL        2020-06-16     1,000
JBLU       2020-06-28     1,000
RDSA       2020-06-11     1,000
AAL        2020-06-21     1,000
```

Ideally, I am looking to create custom groupings where it outputs a table that sums totals for groups such as tech companies (AAPL, MSFT, AMZN) and airline companies (JBLU, AAL) and ignores other values (RDSA), like such:

```
Class                  Value
Airlines               5,000
Tech Companies         4,000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case`  expression. The idea is to use the `where` clause to filter on the `symbol`s you are interested in, and then decode them in the `select` clause:

```
select
    case when symbol in ('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN') 
        then 'Tech Companies'
        else 'Airlines'
    end class,
    sum(value) value
from mytable
where symbol in ('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'JBLU', 'AAL')
group by 1
```

The positional form of `group by` comes handy to avoid repeating the `case` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when symbol in ('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN') then 'Tech'
             when symbol in ('JBLU', 'AAL') then 'Airlines'
        end) as class, sum(value)
from t
group by class;
```

That said, I would recommend having a `symbols` table with a column that specifies the class.